# Calculate the Poll Result

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a page from where users can take a poll and submit their response. A poll contains
1. Poll title/Subject
2. Question/Heading (Can be One or more)
3. four options for each question (can select only one option)

The poll response is stored in MySQL table,

1. id int(11)
2. poll_headingid int(11)
3. user_id int(11)
4. response varchar(50)
5. subject_id int(11)

I want to calculate that how many percentages of users have submitted a response to each question. I tried to use following query and got the following result

[image]

Can anyone please help me

Comment: Put your tables structures regarding your expectation. use this http://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for such basic question, but I figured it out. The correct query was

```
select response, count(*) / (select count(*) from tbl_parent) * 100 as 
percentage from poll_result 
WHERE response='d' 
AND poll_headingid=12 
AND subject_id=4
```